# Libreoffice macro average calculation

Tags: macros, average, libreoffice

REM  *****  BASIC  *****

```
Sub hell_world
    dim hell_world as object
    hell_world = Range("G31:G42")
    Range("H45") = WorksheetFunction.Average(hell_world)
End Sub
```

I have that and I get the error:

```
BASIC runtime error.
Sub-procedure or function procedure not defined.
```

What should I do? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [XFunctionAccess](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XFunctionAccess.html) as described in `6.28. Use FunctionAccess to call Calc Functions` of [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php).

```vb
Sub CallAverage
    Dim oSheet, oRange, oCell, nResult, oFuncAcc
    oSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
    oRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("G31:G42")
    oCell = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("H45")
    oFuncAcc = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
    nResult = oFuncAcc.callFunction("Average", Array(oRange))
    oCell.setValue(nResult)
End Sub
```

Comment: I get the error:
BASIC runtime error.
Property or method not found: ActiveSheet.

Comment: Be sure to run the macro from a Calc spreadsheet, not from the Basic window or from Writer.  Another option is to write it like this: `oSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets(0)`.  But again, this will only work when `ThisComponent` is a spreadsheet.